# silverlight plugin is not working on server

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, mime, silverlight-plugin

i am using silverlight plugin 3.0 to display the chart.it is working fine on local pc but it is not working on server,it is not displaying any thing.

i have checked the MIME type also in iis.its over there.

please tell me whats the problem

thanking you
samir

Comment: "is working fine on local pc but it is not working on server", do you mean its working when the XAP is being served from your local PC but doesn't work when the XAP is served from the Server?  If so are you using the same client machine when viewing it on the server?

Comment: Does the machine meet the system requirements for Silverlight?

Comment: "Does the machine meet the system requirements for Silverlight? " can you tell me what is the basic system requirement?but it is a simple plugin.just like flash

Comment: "If so are you using the same client machine when viewing it on the server" can you please tell me what exactly should i do. i am not getting you.i have tried on another pc also but still the same problem.

Comment: if you want to check then please open " ind107.cfmdeveloper.com " then click on checkbox named "New Window" in the bottom of the page. then click on "Generate" button in the bottom. it will open a new window to display the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule out the chart component itself, have you tried doing a simple "hello world" type application to see if it works?

This should test to see if it is the chart component/data source for it, or a general problem with your server/host and Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It being a server, is IE in Extra Security Mode? It might not load up silverlight at all.
Do any silverlight things work? (I usually test with the gallery at silverlight.net).

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I used a perpetuum repoting tool. I had to create reporting services and these services are accessed by reporting viewer from client side. I forgot to change reporting services url. I put "localhost" and everything was blank(I saw blank page when access report).

so check if there is any issue like this...
or check this url about "URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(v=vs.95).aspx